# How to add a managed metadata field to a page layout?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, page-layout, managed-metadata

I have a managed meta data field. I have this in the page layout

```
<SharePointWebControls:CheckBoxChoiceField ID="MultipleLookupField8" FieldName="MM_x0020_Department" runat="server"/>
```

But I get the error

```
Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField' to type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldMultiChoice'.
```

How can I display the managed metadata as a multichoice picker?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Register taxonomy namespace

```
<%@ Register Tagprefix="Taxonomy" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
```

And than use the following taxonomy control:

```
 <Taxonomy:TaxonomyFieldControl FieldName="MM_x0020_Department" InputFieldLabel="MM Department" runat="server"></Taxonomy:TaxonomyFieldControl>
```